# react-native get image dimensions of base64 image

Tags: image, react-native

I have the following code:

```
let imgSrc =resolveAssetSource("data:image/png;base64,"+img); 
console.log(imgSrc);
let img = <Image source={{uri:"data:image/png;base64,"+img}} style={{width:imgSrc.width/2, height:imgSrc.height/2}} />;
```

But the code crashes because imgSrc is null.  How do I get the width and height of a base64 encoded image such that I can use it in my `<Image style={} />` element?

Comment: Did you try giving percentage width and height? **Example:** `{ width: '50%', height: '50%'}` I'm not sure if its going to work.

Comment: @bennygenel Thanks Benny, but what I really want are the actual image dimensions so that I can run it through a few more calculations which affects other components on the site. So getting a handle on the actual dimensions is what I need.

Comment: What you can do is create a dummy Image with opacity 0 and use onLayout prop to get measurements of the component and then use those values to apply custom values to the visual Image component.

Comment: @John Did you ever manage to achieve this?

Comment: @kuhr no I didn't.  I ended up with a work around where I used a separate backend/server side script to inform me the dimensions of the images ahead of time.

Comment: @John I ended up using Image.getSize() (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#getsize) to get image width and height from an image URI.

Comment: @kuhr does it actually work with `data:image/png;base64....` ?  Ie. base64 encoded images as opposed to a URI?

Comment: @John Si senor: 
let uri = "data:image/png;base64," + image;
Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {...});

Answer (score 4):

Get dimensions by the following way works for me.

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

Image.getSize(`data:image/png;base64,${img}`, (width, height) => {console.log(width, height)});
```